# ¿Como resolver error de indices Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.x

Saludos tengo la funcion del codigo que se muestra a continuación:

```
def triangulateGraph(graph,imagesize):
newGraph = graph
n = newGraph.str.shape[0]
X = np.zeros((n,4))
colIms = np.array([imagesize[1], imagesize[0]]).reshape((2, 1))
imsize = colIms.repeat(len(graph.frames), axis=1)
for i in range(n):
    validCamera = np.where(graph.ObsIdx[i] != -1)[0]
    P = np.zeros((3,4,validCamera.shape[0]))
    x= np.zeros((validCamera.shape[0],2))
    cnt=int(0)
    #Consigue los puntos en el plano de la camara y la matriz de proyeccion
    for ind in validCamera:
        x[cnt,:] = newGraph.obsVal[newGraph.ObsIdx[i][ind],:]
        P[:,:,cnt] = np.dot(newGraph.focal,newGraph.mot[:,:,ind])
        cnt+=1

    X[i,:] = vgg_X_from_xP_nonlin(x,P,imsize,X=None)
allscales = X[:,3].reshape((n, 1))
newGraph.str = X[:,0:3] / np.hstack([allscales,allscales,allscales])
return newGraph
```

cuando llamo la funcion en otro script me esta generando un error de indices:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 104, in <module>
graphList[i] = triangulateGraph(graphList[i],imageSize)
File "D:\DOCUMENTOS\GitHub\Structure-from-motion-python\utils\graph.py", line 84, in triangulateGraph
x[cnt,:] = newGraph.obsVal[newGraph.ObsIdx[i][ind],:]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or 
boolean arrays are valid indices
```

como se puede observar el error se genera por los indices en la linea:

```
x[cnt,:] = newGraph.obsVal[newGraph.ObsIdx[i][ind],:]
        P[:,:,cnt] = np.dot(newGraph.focal,newGraph.mot[:,:,ind])
        cnt+=1
```

no he podido dar con el error, estoy trabajando con la version 3.9 de python en windows, y el codigo original está escrito en python 2, lo he pasado a python 3, pero no he podido seguir avanzando de ahí debido a ese error. He intentado colocando indices como muestra el mensaje de error, pero este se sigue presentando.

Comment: Has un ```print(x[cnt,:])```

Comment: sería asi: for ind in validCamera:
            print(x[cnt,:]) =newGraph.obsVal[newGraph.ObsIdx[i][ind],:]
            P[:,:,cnt] = np.dot(newGraph.focal,newGraph.mot[:,:,ind])
            cnt+=1

Comment: así me sigue generando el error..

Comment: No solo pon lo que te dije  abajo del segundo for